# How to display website desktop version as mobile version

Tags: android, android-webview, user-agent

I have website url which loads as a full desktop version in my web view instead of mobile version. It loads fine on IOS but not on Android. Is this a problem with user agent not been detected or?
I'm trying to load this website www.mercedesbenzstadium.com

Comment: Are you changing the webview user-agent ? Cuz its defualt mode is on mobbile view .

Comment: webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Mobile Safari/537.36");
                webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
                webView.loadUrl(url);

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit the webview settings

```
  mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

**setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)** loads the WebView completely zoomed out
**setUseWideViewPort(true)** makes the Webview have a normal viewport (such as a normal desktop browser)

Comment: That din't help. I want the desktop version to be displayed as a mobile version.